# Using HTML Helper to add class to a string in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using an HTML helper to bring an image into the code

```
<div class="text-center">
     @Html.ThemeImage("logo.png")
</div>
```

I need to apply a class to this, but when i try it says i can't assign it to a string.  The image is pulled in through an extension ends up laying it out as img src.

My extension code is like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ThemeImage(this HtmlHelper helper, string fileName, string alt = "", int width = 0, int height = 0, string cssClass = "", string id = "")
    {
        var clientFolder = string.Format("{0}/Content/{1}/Images", HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath, AppSettings.ClientName);
        var fullFileName = string.Format("{0}/{1}", clientFolder, fileName);

        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", fullFileName);
        if (alt != "")
        {
            builder.MergeAttribute("alt", alt);
        }
        if (width != 0)
        {
            builder.MergeAttribute("width", width.ToString());
        }
        if (height != 0)
        {
            builder.MergeAttribute("height", height.ToString());
        }
        if (cssClass != "")
        {
            builder.MergeAttribute("class", cssClass);
        }
        if (id != "")
        {
            builder.MergeAttribute("id", id);
        }
        //var imgString = String.Format("<img src='{0}' alt='{1}' width='{2}' height='{3}' class='{4}' id='{5}'/>", fullFileName, alt, width, height, cssClass, id);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
```

Comment: Use AddCssClass() method?

Comment: I need to be able to write it in the .cshtml

Comment: change `builder.MergeAttribute("class", cssClass);` to `builder.AddCssClass(cssClass);`

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Stephen's answer worked.